# Freshchat for react native bad file provider error

Tags: react-native, freshdesk

I am integrating Freshdesk in react native using the instructions in the link below:

https://support.freshchat.com/support/solutions/articles/50000000467-freshchat-react-native-sdk-integration-steps

After I finished the steps, I'm getting the error:

```
Missing/Bad FileProvider for Freshchat. Camera capture will fail in devices running Nougat or later versions of OS (error code 354)
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

I'm using react native 0.61.4

Comment: Resolved? Facing same

Comment: Probably not any solution. Don't support nougat or later.

Answer (score 6):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

try changing `android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"` to `android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"`

```
<application>

<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.mypackage.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/freshchat_file_provider_paths" />
</provider>
</application>
```

**values/strings.xml**

```
<string name="freshchat_file_provider_authority">com.mypackage.provider</string>
```

[Ref](https://support.freshchat.com/support/solutions/articles/50000000207-freshchat-android-sdk-integration-steps)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make cameraCaptureEnabled property false like so:

```
const freshchatConfig = new FreshchatConfig(
YOUR_CHAT_APP_ID,
YOUR_APP_KEY,
);

freshchatConfig.domain = YOUR_DOMAIN;
freshchatConfig.cameraCaptureEnabled = false;
```

This solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this solution, it will help you to resolve this issue.

```
var freshchatConfig = new FreshchatConfig(APP_ID, APP_KEY); 
freshchatConfig.cameraCaptureEnabled = false;
```

Use `false` instead of `true`.

Comment: This isn't a solution. You are disabling the camera capture altogether.

Comment: I even have it disabled and still receive the same

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I found that **another app is using the same "android:authorities" I had for freshchat provider.**

To solve this just give **"android:authorities"** a unique name and make sure it's not used by another app.

E.g.:
Your app name is called: APPX ... Change your android:authorities to com.mypackage.provider.APPX

```
<provider
android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="com.mypackage.provider.APPX"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/freshchat_file_provider_paths" /> </provider>
```